# focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT) in vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android-layout

I have 2 EditTexts and 1 TextView in an xml file in a vertical LinearLayout, with hight 0dp and weight 1, TextView onClick fires the below code.
 I need the focus to move to the "next" EditText, but when the last EditText has the focus, the viewToRight points to the EditText above it when it suppose to be null. the problem goes away if I remove hight 0 and weight 1
and give hight of wrap_content.
How can I get viewToRight to have the correct value with my current xml.
The code below gets used with other view arrangements and I expected focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT) to "know" when there is no view to the right in a vertical linearLayout.

```
            View viewCurrent = getCurrentFocus();
        View viewToRight = viewCurrent.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        View viewToDown = viewCurrent.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

        if (viewToRight != null && viewToRight instanceof EditText) {
            viewToRight.requestFocus();
        } else if (viewToDown != null && viewToDown instanceof EditText) {
            viewToDown.requestFocus();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to write a code which checks for the parent viewGroup and decide which direction to get its next view to check.

```
    @Nullable
public View getForwardEditText(View currentView) {
    View viewNext = null;
    assert currentView != null;
    View parent = (View) currentView.getParent();
    if (parent instanceof LinearLayout) {
        int i = ((LinearLayout) parent).getOrientation();
        if (i == 1) {   //vertical
            viewNext = currentView.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        } else {    //must be horizontal
            viewNext = currentView.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        }
    } else if (parent instanceof RelativeLayout) {
        if (currentView.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN) != null) {
            viewNext = currentView.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        } else if (currentView.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT) != null) {
            viewNext = currentView.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_RIGHT);
        }
    }
    if (viewNext instanceof EditText) {
        return viewNext;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```